# What's wrong with this WordPress code?

Tags: php, wordpress, footer, if-statement

I want the following code to show the pagination if there are more than, or equal to, five wordpress posts on a page.  I don't know how to select the post.  This is basically why I need to do this:  For example, If I go to a category that has 6 posts, and click on the bottom navigation to go see the last post from that category—since I only allow 5 posts per page—the nav works perfectly! BUT..if there is a category that only has 2 posts, and I allow 5, the styling for that nav still shows up. Is there an if/else statement that allows me to say, "if page displays < 5 posts, show this footer (without the posts_nav_link included) ?"

```
div class="wrapper">
<div class="pagination">
<?if(count($yourpostvariable)>=5){?>    
<li id="left">
      <?php posts_nav_link('','<span class="previous">&rarr;</span>','<span class="next">&larr;</span>'); ?>
   </li>
  <?};?>
</div><!-- end .pagination -->
</div><!-- end .wrapper -->
```

Comment: where is `$yourpostvariable` defined?

Comment: I don't know.  That's suppost to represent the selection for the WP article on the page.  I don't know how to select the WP article from the page

Comment: try modifying <?if(count($yourpostvariable)>=5){?>  to <?php if(count($yourpostvariable)>5){ ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){

echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look'.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';

}
?>
```